# Python crash when downloading image as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, scipy, urllib

Why does the following code crash python? Is there an easier/better way to download an image and convert it to a numpy array?

```
from pylab import *
from urllib import request
captcha=imread(request.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/etc/CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=35&characters=4&b=123'))
```

Note that this causes the python interpreter to exit rather than just printing a stack trace.

Comment: It doesn't crash: `NameError: name 'imread' is not defined`.

Comment: @Bakuriu You have to import pylab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `imread` can not detect the image type and defaults to `png`.
2. matplotlib's [_png.read_png crashes on Python 3 with urllib.request object](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1650).
3. the `request.urlopen` object is missing a seek function and does not work with PIL (PIL is used by matplotlib to read non-png images).

This code works for me on win-amd64-py3.3:

```
from pylab import *
from urllib import request
from io import BytesIO
url = 'http://pastebin.com/etc/CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&height=35&characters=4&b=123'
data = BytesIO(request.urlopen(url).read())
captcha = imread(data, format='jpg')
```